# Windows Forms DataGridView hosted in WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have an application that is using the Windows Forms `DataGridView` that can’t be replaced With WPF `DataGrid`.
The problem is the visual appearance of the `DataGridView` **scroll bars**.
I want to style them differently, because all my application scroll bars looks different.

Is there a way to do this from WPF ?

Thanks, Avi.

Comment: Why don't you use wpf `DataGrid` instead? What feature it lacks?

Comment: I need Acess to each Cell in the DataGrid , in wpf you get only the row and it works with binding.

Comment: @user2839567 it is strongly recommended that you LEARN how to use proper DataBinding in WPF as opposed to insisting on useless dinosaur technologies and the horrible HACKS associated with them. Whatever you're trying to do probably takes 10% the amount of time and code in WPF than the equivalent winforms. Not to mention that winforms is useless and does not support any amount of customization.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will do the job for you but you could disable scroll bars for the `DataGridView` and wrap the `WindowsFormsHost` in a `ScrollViewer`.

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host"></WindowsFormsHost>
</ScrollViewer>
```

C#:

```
forms.DataGridView dgv = new forms.DataGridView
{
    ScrollBars = forms.ScrollBars.None
};
...
host.Child = dgv;
```